# Ionic pinchin and pinchout gestures don't seem to work with android

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, hammer.js, gestures

this is my pinch zone.

```
<div class="pinch-div" #pinchDiv></div>
```

related properties

```
gesture: Gesture;
@ViewChild('pinchDiv') element;
```

initialization

```
this.angle = 15;
this.gesture = new Gesture(this.element.nativeElement);
this.gesture.listen();
//this.gesture.on('pinch', e => this.pinchEvent(e, this.angle));

this.gesture.on('pinchin', e => this.pinchInEvent(e, this.angle));
this.gesture.on('pinchout', e => this.pinchOutEvent(e, this.angle));
```

functions

```
    pinchEvent(event, angle){
        console.log('pinch event detected');
        angle += 3;

        if(angle > 215){
            angle = 215
        }

        if(angle < 15){
            angle = 15;
        }

        console.log(angle);
        this.angleChanged.next(angle);
    }

    pinchInEvent(event, angle){
        if(angle >= 15){
            angle -= 3;
        }
        this.angleChanged.next(angle);
    }

    pinchOutEvent(event, angle){
        if(angle <= 215){
            angle += 3;
        }
        this.angleChanged.next(angle);
    }
```

Observations

pinchEvent() fires up in **android** even if two fingers are pressed down within the pinch zone. If I hold two fingers in #pinchDiv, i get bunch of 'pinch event detected' logs. I don't think holding down two fingers is a pinch. However, upon commenting out that line and only listening to 'pinchin' and 'pinchout', my pinchInEvent() and pinchOutEvent() are not fired on respective gestures. 
On the other hand, weird behavior of pinchEvent() firing on just two fingers hold is not observed and 'pinchin' and 'pinchout' are fired just fine in **IOS**. I'm not sure if there is some quirk of android that I need to add. I'm just looking for some directions and recommendations.

Comment: Hi Anjil, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I was not able to. I abandoned gestures and moved towards a knob to fulfill what I wanted to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669511/whats-the-scoop-on-pinch-to-zoom-gesture-with-ionic3-and-hammer-js - I had somewhat similar experiences... But I noticed on Android it seemed to fire pinchin/out correctly first time... then invert stutf.