# What's the scoop on Pinch to Zoom Gesture with Ionic3 and Hammer.JS?

Tags: ionic3, hammer.js, pinchzoom

**I need to be able to do pinch to zoom to scale font sizes, on both Android and iOS. (Not just a regular image per numerous examples I've seen when Googling). Can someone let me know if theres an easy way to do this in Ionic 3?**

1. [Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures), infers you can use (pinch). But this never works out of the box.
2. I know Ionic uses Hammer.JS under the covers... per [this source](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/gestures/hammer.ts).
3. [Ionic Forums](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/pinch-gesture-is-not-working/69564/4) suggests you can enable it using a combination of `@ViewChild` and manually adding `listen` and `on` handler.

   Then for some reason the event never fires on a Macbook Pro with a touchpad, yet when I upload it to Ionic View event fires when I attempt to do pinch to zoom. I wonder if there's some navigator agent selection that doesn't enable things on the Macbook Pro, because the touchpad should facilitate this?

   Update: Maybe you need the [touch emulator](http://hammerjs.github.io/touch-emulator/) [script](https://github.com/hammerjs/touchemulator) to do things on a Macbook Pro. I was also reading [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW1)

   > Safari on iOS has no windows, scroll bars, or resize buttons.... The user pans by flicking a finger. The
   >   user zooms in by double-tapping and pinch opening, and zooms out by
   >   pinch closing—gestures that are not available for Safari on the
   >   desktop. Because of the differences in the way users interact with web
   >   content, the viewport on the desktop and on iOS are not the same.

   So maybe this may be why Hammer doesn't work on a native Macbook Pro..

When searching on Gestures on the Ionic page you also get this [page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tap-click/Haptic/) (Haptic/Taptic - which it infers is iOS dependent).

I also thought there might be a connection to the way the [viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) is configured in the index.html. But that appears to be a rabbit hole that's not got a clean solution [per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557801/how-do-i-reset-the-scale-zoom-of-a-web-app-on-an-orientation-change-on-the-iphon) and once again this appeared to be iPhone specific.

I've also seen:

[Gestures - Patterns on Material.io](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/gestures.html#gestures-touch-mechanics)

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/android-detecting-a-pinch-gesture-64a0a0ed4b41) on Pinch to Zoom on Android.

Using an alert on the event with JSON.stringify - you get these sort of properties with pinch to Zoom in the iPhone using similar source to the forum.. I manually typed that in by looking at a iPhone alert.. so there may be the odd typo.. and I omitted a lot of the actual values...

**Do people tend to use RxJS debounce with pinch events in order to throttle the rate at which you Zoom In/Out?**

```
{"pointers": [{},{}],
  "changedPointers": [{}],
  "pointerType": "touch",
  "srcEvent":{"isTrusted":true},
  "isFirst":false,
  "isFinal":false,
  "eventType":2
  "center":{"x":158, "y":302}
  "timeStamp":
  "deltaTime":
  "angle":
  "distance":
  "deltaX":,
  "deltaY":,
  "offsetDirection":,
  "overallVelocityX":,
  "overallVelocityY":,
  "overallVelocity":,
  "scale":,
  "rotation":,
  "maxPointers":,
  "velocity":,
  "direction":,
  "target":,
}
```

I also think there's an `"additionalEvent"` property that can be handy for detecting "pinchout" vs "pinchin".. I seems to double fire.

**Whilst that method seems fine on an iPhone (except for multiple events firing)... The Android Samsung Galaxy S4 phone I'm testing on seems to more often than not invert that, and throws up many events. I also subsequently tested on a co-workers Samsung Galaxy S8 which has an up to date browser. I thought I may have needed to package an up to date browser. But I don't think that will solve it either. Without exhaustive testing it looks like Android gives correct answer first time, thereafter it inverts stuff. So I wonder if the co-ordinates of each finger are being cached somehow, so subsequent pinch in and out requests are based on stale data. Is there a HammerJS reset configuration setting?**

I'm aware of these other libraries too (that don't necessitate jQuery too):

[InteractJS](http://interactjs.io/) Again, their canned pinch to Zoom example failed to work on Macbook Pro with touchpad.

[Jester](https://github.com/plainview/Jester)

**Footnote**: The best implementation of pinch to zoom I've seen, that works on both Android and iOS is [this](http://riagora.com/mobile/hammer/) version by Michaël CHAIZE. But from analysing the code it looks to be based on a really early implementation of HammerJS 0.5 and doesn't even use pinch as part of the domain language - just things like drag, transform, tap, double_tap, so it must be facilitating this stuff by a lower level abstraction. Unfortunately this was for images.

Comment: if you are trying to zoom the font sizes other than that any other operation you are trying to do?

Comment: react to pinch to zoom events to assign a calculated class name with 'n' - being an number and assign it to text field. ie class-1, class-2, class-3 etc when 1,2,3 = n - probably some scale from 1 to 5 say. Problem is HammerJS   pinch event fires erratically on Android in version built into Ionic3.

Answer (score 0):

From the inputs of your long explanation after a bit of searching this probably fit to your need but it needs to be enhanced for your version and also some of the parts of it need to be tweaking :

Basically there are

> There are 3 files needed
>
> ```
> ~/src/pages/home/home.ts
> ~/src/pages/home/home.scss
> ~/src/pages/home/home.html
> ```
>
> **home.html**
>
> The `<div #zoom class="zoom">` element is the fixed container that
>   where you need to  attach the events to, and its children are the
>   items that will be zoomed.
>
> **home.scss**
>
> `.zoom` to fill the container size, with a fixed position and the
>   important `touch-action: none` which `HammerJS` needs.
>
> **home.ts**
>
> It takes the Content to figure out the actual size without the footer
>   and headers getting in the way, the `for loop` just adds the `absolute
>   height` of each children of `#zoom.` The original sizes equal to the
>   `viewport` that the `user sees minus the actual size of the content`,
>   since we override the scroll, the viewing of the content which will
>   most likely overflow the bottom and right (because its fixed and can
>   be any size), will be done via panning so we must know how much its
>   overflowing.
>
> the max sizes to pan are the original overflowed size, for now before
>   zooming, and scale will equal to 1 at first. base is to remember where
>   we left off when pinched to zoom.
>
> We initiate the event listening individually*, panend & pancancel as
>   well as pinchend & pinchcancel are each called depending on the timing
>   when you release the fingers so both must be added, to call their
>   respective onEnd function.
>
> **setCoor function**
>
> sets the x & y coordinates making sure that it doesn't go past it's
>   max
>
> **transform function**
>
> moves "translate", and scales the #zoom element, the xx & yy are for
>   resetting the position
>
> **onPinchend function**
>
> sets the base, and sets the limits of the scale
>
> **onPinch function**
>
> sets the scale depending where it left off.

Full code can be get from [Here](https://github.com/p-sebastian/ionic2-pinchzoom) , He has done most of the work , if you need any other functionally to be added you can enhance it .

**Note:** Explanation and Code taken from the [Github](https://github.com/p-sebastian/ionic2-pinchzoom) , try to give credit to that author if it helped you.

Comment: It's odd... since I've already read identical text for something similiar in the form a mobile app that had a image of a postal package with pinch to zoom in it. But the implementation was very amateur... my iPhone is installing an ios update as I write this.. will post back the link to the app. But it was not an answer I'd have accepted because it's so unpolished.. I'll have to take a look and see just how similar this is later.

Comment: @JGFMK i would definitely agree that this may not be your answer. in order to provide a solution we need MVCE in SO, so to start from somewhere i have picked up this one .. as you are working on this repo(atleast i'm guessing) we will be having a `MVCE`,we can work out and modify it with the collective idea,  at-least i would give my best try because its worth to try for to get a solution for good and interesting questions like this

Comment: @JGFMK same app means ?

Comment: This was the app I downloaded onto my iPhone and the pinch to zoom functionality was erratic - not very poiished.  The Michael Chaise example was far more polished - although the version of hammer.js he used was quite old. It's a better starting point in my eyes..

Comment: @JGFMK if you can provide the version of code on which you are working and what are the ideas and where you got stuck would be veryusefull for us to get the solution . because from the description of your problem i searched web and find that this repo would be benefit you , but while comes to reality you already working on a demo app and you got stuck in it . if you can share what you tried might help us to get you through it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157004/discussion-between-webruster-and-jgfmk).